# How do I scroll so a control is visible after expanding a Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have several Expander controls in a wpf usercontrol.
When I expand the Expanders I want to automatically scroll so that the whole Expander is visible, if possible. Or atleast so the newly expanded Expander is as far 'up' as possible.

When i do it now on the bottom one it expands below the window edge and I cant see the controls in the expander without manually scrolling to them.

And i want to do this from XAML and not the codebehind.
It that possible?
Im using a MVVM pattern.

Im assuming that i have to use a Trigger on the Expander but i have no idea how to preform the BringToView functionality

Highlevel layout:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <UserControl>
    <Grid>
      <Expander>
        ...
      </Expander>
      <Expander>
        ...
      </Expander>
      <Expander>
        ...
      </Expander>
    </Grid>
  </UserControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle `Expanded` event and call `BringIntoView()` method:

```
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Expander)sender).BringIntoView();
}
```

Please note that you should use StackPanel or something else instead of `Grid`:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="sv">
    <UserControl>
        <StackPanel>
            <Expander>
                <Border Height="1000" Background="Red"/>
            </Expander>
            <Expander>
                <Border Height="1000" Background="Blue"/>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded">
                <Border Height="1000" Background="Green"/>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Edit**

You might want to use this attached property:

```
public static class ExpanderEx
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BringIntoViewOnExpandProperty =
                           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BringIntoViewOnExpand", 
                                typeof(bool), typeof(ExpanderEx), 
                                new PropertyMetadata(false, OnBringIntoViewOnExpandChanged));


    public static bool GetBringIntoViewOnExpand(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(BringIntoViewOnExpandProperty);
    }
    public static void SetBringIntoViewOnExpand(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BringIntoViewOnExpandProperty, value);
    }  
    private static void OnBringIntoViewOnExpandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is Expander)
        {
            Expander obj = (Expander)d;
            if (e.NewValue.Equals(true)) 
                obj.Expanded += Obj_Expanded; 
            else
                obj.Expanded -= Obj_Expanded;
        }
    }

    private static void Obj_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Expander)sender).BringIntoView();
    }
}
```

and in Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="sv">
    <UserControl>
        <StackPanel>
            <Expander local:ExpanderEx.BringIntoViewOnExpand="True">
                <Border Height="1000" Background="Red"/>
            </Expander>
            <Expander local:ExpanderEx.BringIntoViewOnExpand="True">
                <Border Height="1000" Background="Blue"/>
            </Expander>
            <Expander local:ExpanderEx.BringIntoViewOnExpand="True">
                <Border Height="1000" Background="Green"/>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I tried this, and it worked. But not in a way i made it work :) Im new to wpf so bear with me. Where do i put the ExpanderEx class so that i can reuse this in many views? When i tried it i had to put the class in the same project as the view  AND inside the view codebehind ...that cant be right...

Comment: choose on your preference. Its a separate static class. e.g., Create an **extentions.cs** file and put your extensions there. The important thing is to set [XAML Namespace Declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx) correctly.

Comment: I had it in a static class. Guess i did something wrong when i tested it before. Now i moved the class to a shared project and let VS create the namespace reference in the xaml file, recompiled, and it worked! Thanks, your comment made me try the same thing in another way and that got it working :)

Answer (score 2):

Give each `Expander` this handler for its `Expanded` event. It looks like you're defining the expanders inside a `UserControl`, so getting to the `ScrollViewer` is a problem. One option is to give your `UserControl` a `ScrollViewer` dependency property that the owner will bind to whatever `ScrollViewer` contains it. I don't like that. Instead, I wrote a helper function that looks up the visual tree and finds the nearest parent `ScrollViewer`, if any.

```
private void Expander_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = GetNearestScrollViewerParent();

    if (scrollViewer == null)
        return;

    var expander = (Expander)sender;

    UIElement container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(expander) as UIElement;
    Point relativeLocation = expander.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), container);

    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(relativeLocation.Y);
}

public ScrollViewer GetNearestScrollViewerParent()
{
    for (var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this); 
         parent != null; 
         parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent))
    {
        if (parent is ScrollViewer)
            return parent as ScrollViewer;
    }

    return null;
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Expander" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Expander}}">
        <EventSetter Event="Expanded" Handler="Expander_Expanded" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```